# BIND/named: zone sigilhosting.com/IN: not loaded due to errors

Tags: bind, named-conf

It's been working perfectly until my cPanel license expired and I had to renew it.

I keep getting this error when running named-checkzone:

```
zone sigilhosting.com/IN: NS 'ns1.sigilhosting.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone sigilhosting.com/IN: NS 'ns2.sigilhosting.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone sigilhosting.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

/var/named/sigilhosting.com.db

```
$TTL 14400
sigilhosting.com.       86400   IN      SOA     ns1.sigilhosting.com.   konstantinkeller5.gmail.com.    (
                                            2013122210 ;Serial Number
                                            86400 ;refresh
                                            7200 ;retry
                                            3600000 ;expire
                                            86400 ;minimum
    )
sigilhosting.com.       86400   IN      NS      ns1.sigilhosting.com.
sigilhosting.com.       86400   IN      NS      ns2.sigilhosting.com.
sigilhosting.com.       14400   IN      A       64.186.15.206
localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1
sigilhosting.com.       14400   IN      MX      0       sigilhosting.com.
mail    14400   IN      CNAME   sigilhosting.com.
www     14400   IN      CNAME   sigilhosting.com.
ftp     14400   IN      CNAME   sigilhosting.com.
cpanel  14400   IN      A       64.186.15.206
whm     14400   IN      A       64.186.15.206
204     14400   IN      PTR     sigilhosting.com.
webmail 14400 IN A  64.186.15.206
www.webmail 14400 IN A  64.186.15.206
webdisk.webmail IN A 64.186.15.206
```

/var/named/ns1.sigilhosting.com.db

```
$TTL 14400
@      86400    IN      SOA     ns1.sigilhosting.com. konstantinkeller5.gmail.com. (
            2013121701      ; serial, todays date+todays
            86400           ; refresh, seconds
            7200            ; retry, seconds
            3600000         ; expire, seconds
            86400 )         ; minimum, seconds

ns1.sigilhosting.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.sigilhosting.com.
ns1.sigilhosting.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.sigilhosting.com.
ns1.sigilhosting.com. IN A 64.186.15.204

localhost.ns1.sigilhosting.com. IN A 127.0.0.1

ns1.sigilhosting.com. IN MX 0 ns1.sigilhosting.com.

mail IN CNAME ns1.sigilhosting.com.
www IN CNAME ns1.sigilhosting.com.
ftp IN CNAME ns1.sigilhosting.com.
```

/var/named/ns2.sigilhosting.com.db

```
$TTL 14400
@      86400    IN      SOA     ns1.sigilhosting.com. konstantinkeller5.gmail.com. (
            2013121701      ; serial, todays date+todays
            86400           ; refresh, seconds
            7200            ; retry, seconds
            3600000         ; expire, seconds
            86400 )         ; minimum, seconds

ns2.sigilhosting.com. 86400 IN NS ns1.sigilhosting.com.
ns2.sigilhosting.com. 86400 IN NS ns2.sigilhosting.com.
ns2.sigilhosting.com. IN A 64.186.15.205

localhost.ns2.sigilhosting.com. IN A 127.0.0.1

ns2.sigilhosting.com. IN MX 0 ns2.sigilhosting.com.

mail IN CNAME ns2.sigilhosting.com.
www IN CNAME ns2.sigilhosting.com.
ftp IN CNAME ns2.sigilhosting.com.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that A records are missing for ns1 and ns2 for domain sigilhosting.com.

I would add these records in `/var/named/sigilhosting.com.db` :

```
ns1.sigilhosting.com.            IN A    64.186.15.204
ns2.sigilhosting.com.            IN A    64.186.15.205
```